# How can I show the battery as a percentage on my iPod Touch?

Tags: ipod-touch

On the iPhone, to show the percentage of battery left, I can go into `Settings > General > Usage` and toggle "Battery Percentage" on.

My daughter's iPod touch doesn't have a Usage category.  Is there a way on the iPod touch to display the battery percentage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No iPod Touches can show the battery percentage at the top of the screen (unless you jailbreak them). There are apps in the App Store that will show the battery percentage when you run them, but obviously not all the time.

There's a discussion thread here: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1013295

Comment: Well, that stinks...but thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Interestingly enough, once you jailbreak them, show the percentage and backup to itunes, if you restore to factory defaults and then restore your backup, the percentage will usually come back (and the device will not be jailbroken).

Comment: What is interesting is that I had this working with SBsettings (jailbroken Ipod), made a backup at some point, then upgraded to 9.3 recently. After restoring to the backup I still had numeric battery (and numeric wifi) working with iOS 9.3 (no jailbreak). It's deplorable Apple doesn't offer these simple features natively.

Answer (score 10):

If you would like your your iPod to tell you your battery level as a percentage go to `Settings > General > Accessibility > Triple-click Home`, and select "Toggle VoiceOver". After you are done, go to your home screen and triple click the home button. VoiceOver will activate. Then tap the battery icon. VoiceOver will say the battery percentage aloud. To turn VoiceOver off, triple click the home button again.

This will only work on 3rd-gen or newer iPod touches and iPhone 3GS or newer.

Comment: It "works" but it's pretty clunky. Wonder what genius at Apple thought this was a bright idea...

Answer (score 4):

If jailbroken, SBSettings has a toggle for this.

Answer (score 0):

If your charging an iPod Touch the lock screen will show the current battery percentage briefly when turned on while charging.

Connect working charger percentage should show on screen.

Press power button to lock

Press home or power button once

Watch for battery percentage to show under large current time.

Pretty lame would be nice if Apple could be consistent across all the iDevices for things like this including  battery health and a calculator too.